# Does 'Service with exception' look native to English speakers?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, questions, phrase-usage

I saw this error message on my university's website, which seems weird to me. After googling, I found no other people using this error message in their apps or websites. But some of my schoolmate thought it was decent. How native does this error message seem to native English speakers?

[image]

Comment: It's not meaningful English. I'd guess that this is a computer-generated message that was never intended to be seen by the user.

Comment: Given that it seems to be the website of a university in China, I assume a mistaken use of English.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, but it is one of the best two universities in China, so I wasn't expecting such mistakes.

Comment: Answering your question: not very *natural* and certainly not *native*.

Comment: An [exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) is a term in computing, so the message probably makes sense to the person who programmed it, even though its meaning is very obscure to the user. It's grammatical, but not clear what service is being referred to and even less clear what exception has occurred.

Comment: It could be part of an acceptable longer string; 'exception' is often used attributively 'with exception handling' / 'service with Exception Audit Database Connection'; I've also found an example 'WebAPI calling WCF service with exception: "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending".' Perhaps an 'of' is deleted. But as it stands, unidiomatic and (worse) hard to understand.

Comment: The term *exception* is likely referring to an error, and the term *service* is likely referring to a back-end process supporting the webpage. This non-standard phrasing is in all likelihood indicating that one of the service threw an exception, which itself is common developer speak. This isn't a description a user should ever see.

Comment: The preposition **with** is odd and not idiomatic.  "Exception" is a term of art.  Code encountering an error condition "throws an exception" and the error-handling block "catches the exception".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490156/etymology-of-words-throw-and-catch-when-talking-about-programming-exception

Comment: Why don't you ask them what they mean first instead of asking us if this is good English?

Comment: @Lambie because it is automatically generated error message. I don't know who developed this thing.

Comment: Since the site is Chinese, have you considered that it might just be a bad machine translation.   An "exception" in computer programming is an error. A human being may not have been involved in the translation at all. Perhaps it's supposed to be "Server Error"??  That would be my guess.

Comment: @BillyKerr You are probably right. For example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is meaningless.

It probably relates to "service" (perhaps a mistake for "server", for example a web server) and an "exception" (an condition that occurs in running code when something unexpected occurs such as dividing by zero, or a disk crashing)

And I speculate that some server that the web page depends on "threw an exception" and crashed.  But as I said first, it is meaningless.

Comment: "Service" is also meaningful within computer programming, e.g. "Login service." But it's not meaningful to the end user; this is lazy (or ill-advised) design, passing along "computer-y" language as a user-facing message instead of translating it into something more useful.